# Prove that the product of two continuous functions is continuous using the sequential definition of continuity

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Using the following definition, prove that the product of two continuous functions is continuous.

> Let $f$ be a funtion from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The function
>   f is continuous if for every point $p$, for every sequence $x_n\to p$,
>   $f(x_n)\to f(p)$

Here is my attempt at the proof:

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions that are given.

Therefore:

For every point $p$, for every sequence $a_n\to p$, $f(b_n)\to f(p)$.

For every point $q$, for every sequence $b_n\to p$, $g(b_n)\to g(q)$.

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f\cdot g$. We wish to show that $F$ is continuous. That is, for every point $p$, for every sequence $x_n\to p_o$, one has $F(x_n)\to F(p_o)$.

Take the point $p_o$ to be the product of $p$ and $q$, and the sequence $x_n$ to be the defined as $a_n b_n$. Therefore $x_n \to p_o$.

The function $F(x_n) \to F(p_o)$ if given $\epsilon >0,$ there is some $N$ such that whenever $n>N$, $|F(x_n) - F(p_o)| < \epsilon$

This is where I'm stuck. I think I'm on the right track with taking the product of the two sequences but it seems like I might need to take the proof by contradiction and start with $$|F(x_n) - F(p_o)| \geq \epsilon$$

Is this the correct approach to be taking?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for showing your work. Why are you assuming that $p_0$ is a product? The value of $F$ is given by $F(x)=f(x)g(x)$, not as $f(a)g(b)$ with $ab=x$. So you should not be taking a point that is a product and sequences that converge to the factors. Just take a point $x$, and a sequence converging to $x$, and see what happens to $F(b_n) = f(b_n)g(b_n)$.

Comment: In your eighth paragraph, “$f(x_n)\to f(p_0)$” should be, presumably, “$F(x_n)\to F(p_0)$”.

Comment: sorry about that. Change  has been made

Comment: Yeah, but you also rolled back my title edit to make the tile more informative... fixed.

Comment: My apologies @ArturoMagidin. Thank you for making those changes.

Comment: Take a point $x$, and the sequence converging to $x$, $b_n$.Then $f(b_n)\to f(x)$ and $g(b_n)\to g(x)$ so $f(b_n)g(b_n)\to f(x)g(x)$. Therefore, $F(b_n)\to f(x)g(x)$ ?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also need to state that $F(b_n) \to F(x)$ since $F(x) = f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: You need to show $F(b_n)\to F(x)$; now, $F(b_n)=f(b_n)g(b_n)\to f(x)g(x) = F(x)$. So that’s what you say. Of course you have to justify that middle bit, either by proving it or by invoking previously known theorems about products of sequences that converge.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this: suppose $x_n\to x$. Then, an application of the triangle inequality gives

$|f(x_n)g(x_n)-f(x)g(x)|\le|f(x_n)g(x_n)-f(x)g(x_n)|+|f(x)g(x_n)-f(x)g(x)|=$

$|g(x_n)||f(x_n)-f(x)|+|f(x)||g(x_n)-g(x)|.$

Now, let $x_n\to x$ and use the continuity of $f$ and $g$ at $x$ to conclude that

$|f(x_n)g(x_n)-f(x)g(x)|\to |g(x)|\cdot 0+ |f(x)|\cdot0=0.$